# Adding blink effects, text color, and background text color on selected texts in VS - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, terminal, console

I'm new to c++. I am currently converting my main menu (which is Turbo C++ codes) into Visual Studio. I already found solutions in some functions that I commonly used in Turbo C++. My main problem is, I can't figure out how to manually highlight some selected texts. I used to play with textcolor(COLOR + BLINK); since our professor requires us to do so, but seems like it doesn't work in Visual Studio. I also tried system("color XY"), but it highlight all of the texts displayed lmao. Here's my converted code so far(trimmed).

[image: Here's the image that I want to display in Visual Studio]

```
//| Header
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>
#define clrscr(); system("cls");
#define getch(); _getch()

using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void clreol(void)
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}

//Refresher Loop Variable
int refresh = 1;

char main_input;
char s_input;
char se_input;
char l_input;
char l_option;
char a_input;
int trigger;

//|-------------------------------------------------------------(Main Lobby)-
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(void) {
clrscr();

while(refresh == 1)
do {
clrscr();

gotoxy(30, 8);  
system("Color 80");
cout << "      Main Menu      ";


gotoxy(30, 10); system("Color D7");
cout << "A"; 
system("Color 07");  cout << " - Sequence";

gotoxy(30, 11); system("Color 17");
cout << "B";    
system("Color 07"); cout << " - Selection";

gotoxy(30, 12); system("Color 27");
cout << "C";    
system("Color 07"); cout << " - Iteration";

gotoxy(30, 13); system("Color 67");
cout << "D";    
system("Color 07"); cout << " - Arrays final exam   ";

gotoxy(30, 14); system("Color 47");
cout << "E";    
system("Color 07"); cout << " - Exit";

gotoxy(30, 16);
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
            cin >> main_input;

switch(main_input) {
    case 'A': sequence();
    break;

    case 'B': selection();
    break;

    case 'C': loops();
    break;

    case 'D': arrays();
    break;

    case 'E':
        exit(0);
    break;
} // End of switch

} while(refresh == 1); // End of do while

getch();

}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You may be looking for [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute). It doesn't support blinking, but does support changing foreground and background color.

Comment: Thanks :),. Blinking is my last problem xD.

Comment: I don't believe Windows console natively supports blinking, the way DOS did. I suspect the only way would be to run a timer that repeatedly updates character attributes, possibly with `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use ```WriteConsoleOutputAttribute```? I also tried the SetConsoleCursorPosition onto my code, but the problem is, I can't input my choice since the cursor's position keeps in one place, as if it is trapped.

Comment: ```WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(hStdOut, wColors[1], strlen(Text), s, &cWritten);```  I don't know what's the problem here. It keeps telling me that the second parameter cannot convert from WORD to const WORD. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: The second parameter should be a pointer to an array of `WORD`'s, not a single `WORD`. The third parameter is the size of this array. Even if you want to set a number of cells to the same color, you have to prepare an array of attributes, possibly all the same, one for each cell. Or else call `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute` multiple times setting one cell each.

Comment: The text is now blinking. Though my problem now is about exiting threads in multithreading. Anyways, thanks a lot sir :)

Answer (score 1):

**For blinking (using escape sequence):**

```
cout << "\033[5mExit?\033[0m"; //Blinking text
/*Where \033[5m turns on blinking and 
  \033[0m turns off every attribute including blinking (in short resets) but previously applied attributes are not effected
*/
cout << "uneffected line"; //No attributes applied(using default attributes)
```

See the complete documentation/Manual or Codes for different colors or actions
https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797

**Method 2:**
**Use SetConsoleTextAttribute():**

```
HANDLE Console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(Console, 10); //for Green
SetConsoleTextAttribute(Console, 175); //for white text with green background like you asked in image in Option C.
```

Use this Image as **Manual/Reference**:

[image]